# Rust move variable to new tokio task

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

**Edit**

As `@user4815162342` stated in the comments, one can move the variable  using `tokio::task::spawn(async move { return client.start_autosharded().await });`

**Original Post**

In the Serenity framework, in the `serenity::client::Client` struct, there is a method called `start_autosharded(&mut self)`. I want this worker to run in another thread, so I am calling it in `tokio::task::spawn()`. However, `spawn()` wants to borrow the `Client` instance with a static lifetime, however, it is dropped at the end of the function it is created in.

This is definitely the last time I call any method or change any field on the `Client` instance, so how could I entirely give up ownership of the `Client` instance to the new thread?

```
 --> src/bot_worker.rs:101:45
    |
101 |     let shard_join_handle = tokio::task::spawn(client.start_autosharded());
    |                                                ^^^^^^--------------------
    |                                                |
    |                                                borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                                                argument requires that `client` is borrowed for `'static`
...
127 | }
    | - `client` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

I have looked into allocating the `Client` on the heap with `Box` and spawning the thread from that, however, I run into the same lifetime issues.

```
error[E0597]: `*client` does not live long enough
   --> src/bot_worker.rs:101:45
    |
101 |     let shard_join_handle = tokio::task::spawn(client.start_autosharded());
    |                                                ^^^^^^--------------------
    |                                                |
    |                                                borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                                                argument requires that `*client` is borrowed for `'static`
...
127 | }
    | - `*client` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I also considered `Arc` and looked into that documentation, however, I don't see anything suggestion I would be able to provide a static lifetime for the thread.

Comment: Try moving `client` into an async block, and passing that to `spawn`: `tokio::task::spawn(async move { client.start_autosharded() })`

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Please post an answer instead of editing the question to include the answer.

Comment: You should post your answer as answer to make it more visible for other people with similar issue.